# Create XY chart, React-Native

Tags: react-native, charts

How can I create basic xy chart in react-native? For example I have data:

```
chart_data = [
[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[0,0]
]
```

This is the points of a square. Most of all libraries offer to create line chart, which will create other line-type chart and the result for this points would be - trapeze. Help me, please

Answer (score 1):

You should try [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), there's even a [react native wrapper for it](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

Use [react-native-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart)

```
import React, { StyleSheet, View, Component } from 'react-native';
import Chart from 'react-native-chart';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    chart: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
});

const data = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [3, 7],
    [4, 9],
];

class SimpleChart extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Chart
                    style={styles.chart}
                    data={data}
                    verticalGridStep={5}
                    type="line"
                 />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that MPAndroidChart supports Android only, whereas react-native-chart supports both Android and iOS.

Example charts:
[image]

Comment: I tried to use that library. If I will replace data from your example with points for any shape(square as in the topic), I will get the result I am not need in. May be I am not understanding how to use that module. Can you explain to me how should I generate data points for to plot square

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and its methods. There you can draw points lines or shapes...